# Adafruit OLED (128x64) display very dimmed?

Tags: python, display, adafruit

I bought the Adafruit 128x64 OLED Bonnet and tested it with the demo program. Unfortunately the luminosity is very low and it is not satisfying:

[image]

I have tried to adjust the contrast from 0 to 255 but the highest I can get is far from ideal.

Is this normal ?

In the datasheet it is said `IREF` should be equal to 12.5 uA, but I can measure a 390 kOhm resistor:

```
I = U / R = (VCC - 2.5) / 390k = (3.3 - 2.5) / 390'000 = 2 uA
```

I tried to change this resistance to 64k but I get roughly the same luminosity

What did I miss ?

```py
import board
import busio
from digitalio import DigitalInOut, Direction, Pull
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import adafruit_ssd1306

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
disp = adafruit_ssd1306.SSD1306_I2C(128, 64, i2c)
disp.inverse(1)
disp.contrast(250)
```